# Semantic Tokens in MarkupString / MarkupContent

Tags: vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

Is it possible to use `MarkdownString`/`MarkupContent` with `code` or `pre` with `span` to emulate semantic tokens in `Hover`? If so, is it possible to access the colors from the user's theme using only the CSS on the `span` elements? Ideally I would like to avoid using anything VSCode specific.

I saw https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97409 but there was no solution.

Comment: Are you trying to do something that `appendCodeblock(value: string, language?: string): MarkdownString` doesn't do?  That gives you syntax highlighting.  https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#MarkdownString

Comment: @Mark I'm specifically looking for semantic tokens not TextMate syntax highlighting. I want to manually specify the colors and ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manually set colors for code you can try this:

```js
// using your fileSelector
let disposable = vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider('plaintext', {
  provideHover(document, position) {

    const codeBlock = `<code><span style="color:#f00;background-color:#fff;">const</span> a = 12</code>`;

    const markdown = new vscode.MarkdownString();
    // markdown.appendCodeblock(codeBlock, "javascript");

    markdown.appendMarkdown(codeBlock);
    markdown.supportHtml  = true;
    markdown.isTrusted = true;

    return new vscode.Hover(markdown, new vscode.Range(position, position));
  }
});
```

`<pre>` also works, instead of `<code>`, but I think `<code>` looks better.

[image: hover with span colored code demo]

Comment: Is it possible to use colors from the user's theme using CSS? I want it to match the code in the file which is highlighted with semantic tokens.

Comment: Something like the `var(--vscode-editor-foreground);` mentioned https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#theming-webview-content

Comment: Also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/32813

Comment: Which language are you doing this for?

Comment: I was considering using this in the Idris2 LSP