# How to change the syntax color of the hover tooltip in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing my own color scheme for VS Code. But the problem is the tooltip appear's when I hover the mouse to some variable or function like this picture.

[image: tooltip]

I've customized the syntax highlighting for variables, function names, classes and etc.. in Python and other languages that I frequently use. However, the tooltip text remains in a uniform pink color. Is there a way to apply my syntax color settings to the tooltip as well?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from the information in the question post, but if you're trying to change the colours using semantic highlighting customization instead of TextMate grammar token customization, then that's not supported. See [No semantic highlighting in HoverProvider code blocks #97409](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97409), where maintainer [Alexandru Dima responded](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97409#issuecomment-627226045):

> I think this is highly unlikely to ever be done, because semantic highlighting typically requires a project / a lot of metadata. For example, a snippet of C++ cannot just be "semantically colored" without a lot of metadata around it, to get the semantic highlighting correct it is very important to have the entire context of the snippet, etc. The same applies for almost any other language I can think of, like Java, TypeScript, etc.

I.e. To the extent that it's possible for what you want to do, use `tokenColors` instead of `semanticTokenColors` for this. You might find [descendent selectors](https://macromates.com/manual/en/scope_selectors#descendant_selectors) useful.

You may also be interested in [Semantic Tokens in MarkupString / MarkupContent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72654126/11107541).